# Network module on a multi-module project android

Tags: android, performance, kotlin, retrofit, multi-module

I'm trying to implement this multi-module design on my app, the thing is that I'm thinking about create an "api" or "network" module where I create the retrofit instance (I'm using Dagger2, but it doesn't matter, if you have an example or pseudo with any other DI framework feel free).

### Problem?

I've been working on an app that I had this similar architecture but it ended up with a big module because I had organised the instance of a retrofit and then inside of it a sub-packages with each feature where I have the services and the responses.

This helped me with a problem that I had for instance, use the same service on a different features.

Example

1. Home feature I need to call the Feature1Service to show X
2. Feature1 need to call Feature1Service to show more stuff

I've thought with a solution that instead of creating the api or network module create every service inside of that feature, but doing this is a problem.

So I'd like to listen options or if you have worked with that app with modules how did you do that?

### Short question

How do you use on multi-module project where you share services between features? (Retrofit)

Comment: not sure if I'm understanding the question exactly. You've tried having an api module and this didn't work for you because you had to create an instance of the service whenever you used it?

Comment: The question is to propose an architecture to achieve this multi-modulebut the problem I've faced creating a module called Api is I had everything inside of it, like all the models, all the services etc... and I wanted to put this on each module, but the problem occurs when trying to use a service on another feature.

Comment: I guess this is a very broad question. I've done it like you in the past, but changed it to have a module which is split into submodule. Each submodule implements a different layer and one of the submodules is an actual public api that others can depend on and use features from that module. I think this is similar to what square does. In any case, I don't have a comprehensive answer to post.

Comment: Can you share with me this "is similar to what square does"? So I can take a look?

Comment: oh yeah, I should've done that in the first place. So [this](https://www.droidcon.com/media-detail?video=380843878) is a presentation on what I meant.

Comment: I see the way Square is doing it, but I want to understand yours, is a bit tricky one? In terms of Retrofit and everything I'd like to know how you separate to just use only one Retrofit and then have the services divided between freatures

Comment: I'm just reluctant to post an answer as it won't be comprehensive in any means and would just be my own approach. But at the same time I would like to share. What I can suggest is: I'll create a github repo with my approach and share it here in the comments. It'll take a bit though. Maybe late today :S

Comment: @Fred that would be perfect tho... let me know if you do this :)

Comment: sorry it took too long. I hope this helps a bit: https://github.com/fgoncalves/nasapics.android